# Is there a template engine for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, template-engine, node.js

I'm experimenting with building an entire web application using Node.js. Is there a template engine similar to (for example) the Django template engine or the like that at least allows you to extend base templates?

Comment: I just found out that JavaScript V8 engine is faster than Ruby, PHP, and Python. Amazingly fast for a dynamic language. Slower than Java and C#, though.

Comment: @Nosredna: How can Java possibly be faster than anything?! ;)

Comment: @Daniel Java is actually pretty fast these days, beating everything but Ada, C and C++ in Debian's Shootout benchmarks.

Comment: Anyone who doesn't care about syntax, productivity and anything else but performance, should be using [Raphters](https://github.com/DanielWaterworth/raphters) (web framework for C)

Comment: node.js is not about the language. It's totally about the design and the way js handles IO, which is brilliant. You could make ruby web frameworks run fast if you redesigned it's IO libraries.

Comment: @DanielSloof Javascript not Java...

Comment: @korri: read the whole comment thread :)

Comment: @DanielSloof woops, my bad !

Comment: If you really don't mind about the syntax or "beauty" of a language but performance only, I hear assembler is pretty fast ;)

Comment: @arg20 You might find this answer interesting :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684364/why-arent-programs-written-in-assembly-more-often/2685541#2685541

Comment: @grasGendarme I was being sarcastic dude.

Comment: you can try jade http://jade-lang.com/

Comment: npm install templetize - Full syntax extensible engine, works like a charm!

Answer (score 166):

Check out the Node js modules wiki page. They have listed all the [templating engines](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Modules#templating) supporting node.js.

Comment: The page became deprecated you can find an alternative page on [Visionmedia's wiki](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki) and [the chapter about templates](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki#wiki-template-engines).

Comment: @ThomasPotaire It became deprecated because they suggest to use npm search instead.

Answer (score 53):

You should be able to use mustache.js, if it doesn't work send me the issues and I'll get it fixed because I'm about to be using them in node.js anyway.

http://github.com/janl/mustache.js

I know that it works without a DOM because a bunch of CouchDB standalone apps are using it in a Spidermonkey view server.

Comment: There is also a blog post about using Mustache and Underscore together with Node.js: http://boldr.net/create-a-web-app-with-node

Comment: @MKroehnert the link is broken

Answer (score 39):

If you like haml, but want something even better check out http://jade-lang.com for node, I wrote haml.js as well :)

Comment: Jade is pretty cool.  I've just started using it, so can't speak to it's performance, but I like the syntax.  And built-in support in Express is a plus.

Comment: the performance is sufficient, templates should be cached anyway. Plus remember to scale horizontally, not vertically, otherwise you might as well not use a template engine at all and just some functions / concats

Answer (score 14):

There are new templating engines all the time.

underscore.js adds a lot of functional programming support to js, and has templating.

And just today I heard about this: http://github.com/SamuraiJack/Shotenjin-Joosed

Comment: Thumbs up for underscore.js. Awesome library, I use it both for my client side as well as node.js work. Their templating engine is based on John Resig's JS Micro Templating engine (http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) which I have used many times before. Afaik its your best option at this point when working with node.js.

Comment: Do any of these support inheritance?

Comment: @Nick jinjs seems to support inheritance, see the first line: https://github.com/ravelsoft/node-jinjs/blob/master/test/templates/test-extend.tpl

Answer (score 13):

You should take a look at [node-asyncEJS](http://github.com/cramforce/node-asyncEJS), which is explicitly designed to take the asynchronous nature of node.js into account. It even allows async code blocks inside of the template.

Here an example form the documentation:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <% ctx.hello = "World";  %>
    <title><%= "Hello " + ctx.hello %></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1><%? setTimeout(function () { res.print("Async Header"); res.finish(); }, 2000)  %></h1>
    <p><%? setTimeout(function () { res.print("Body"); res.finish(); }, 1000)  %></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try [beardless](https://github.com/marcelklehr/beardless) (it's inspired by weld/plates):

For example:

```
{ post:
  { title: "Next generation templating: Start shaving!"
  , text: "TL;DR You should really check out beardless!"
  , comments:
    [ {text: "Hey cool!"}
    , {text: "Really gotta check that out..."}  ]
  }
}
```

Your template:

```
<h1 data-template="post.title"></h1>
<p data-template="post.text"></p>
<div>
  <div data-template="post.comments" class="comment">
    <p data-template="post.comments.text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<h1>Next generation templating: Start shaving!</h1>
<p>TL;DR You should really check out beardless!</p>
<div>
  <div class="comment">
    <p>Hey cool!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <p>Really gotta check that out...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your answer about your code and the link you referred to. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Would be interesting, how to actually process the file or populate variables within Node

Answer (score 6):

I have done some work on a pretty complete port of the Django template language for Simon Willisons [djangode project](http://github.com/simonw/djangode/) (Utilities functions for node.js that borrow some useful concepts from Django).

See the documentation [here](http://github.com/simonw/djangode/blob/master/TEMPLATES.md).

Answer (score 6):

I use Twig with Symfony and am now dabbling in node.js, so I'm looking at https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js and https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig, which you'll probably like if you use django.

Comment: TwigJS is kind of dead, GitHub says last commit was2years ago. Swig, on he other hand, is pretty acive. I'd go for Swig.

Comment: **FYI**: As of [this commit on Jun 25th 2015](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/commit/20b20e72d6a3a0a73f5c322142aff555be5bd707), the [Swig github claims it is no longer being maintained](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/628). That might change in the future, but as of now, it's something to consider.

Comment: [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) has very similar syntax, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a minimalist approach to templates, you can check out [JSON Template](http://code.google.com/p/json-template/).

A more full-featured alternative is [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/).  It's a bit more similar to something you'd get from Django.

Your mileage may vary for each of these - they're designed for a browser Javascript environment, and not Node.js.

Comment: It's not similar to Django's templates at all, for one Django's templates have *good* documentation. EJS is a struggle to get through and you'll end up reading its source code just to understand what's available to you.

Answer (score 5):

**WARNING : JinJs is not maintained anymore. It is still working but not compatible with the lastest version of express.**

You could try using [jinjs](http://bitbucket.org/ravelsoft/node-jinjs). It is a port of the Jinja, a very good Python templating system. You can install it with npm like this :

```
npm install jinjs
```

in template.tpl :

```
I say : "{{ sentence }}"
```

in your template.js :

```
jinjs = require('jinjs');
jinjs.registerExtension('.tpl');
tpl = require('./template');
str = tpl.render ({sentence : 'Hello, World!'});
console.log(str);
```

The output will be :

```
I say : "Hello, World!"
```

We are actively developing it, a good documentation should come pretty soon.

Answer (score 4):

haml is a good choice for node.js

http://github.com/creationix/haml-js

**haml-js**

```
!!! XML
!!! strict
%html{ xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" }
  %head
    %title Sample haml template
  %body
    .profile
      .left.column
        #date= print_date()
        #address= current_user.address
      .right.column
        #email= current_user.email
        #bio= current_user.bio
```

**html**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Sample haml template
</title></head><body><div class="profile"><div class="left column"><div id="date">January 1, 2009
</div><div id="address">Richardson, TX
</div></div><div class="right column"><div id="email">tim@creationix.com
</div><div id="bio">Experienced software professional...
</div></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've heard good things about {dust} http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/#dust

Answer (score 4):

**Try "vash" - asp.net mvc like razor syntax for node.js**

https://github.com/kirbysayshi/Vash

also checkout: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

---

```
// sample
var tmpl = vash.compile('<hr/>@model.a,@model.b<hr/>');
var html = tmpl({"a": "hello", "b": "world"});
res.write(html);
```

Answer (score 3):

Google's Closure Templates is a natively-JavaScript templating system and a seemingly natural fit with NodeJS. [Here are some instructions](http://www.dashdashverbose.com/2009/11/closure-templates-and-nodejs-server.html) for integrating them.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [PURE](http://wiki.github.com/pure/pure) ?
If you give it a try, feel free to post any trouble you may face at the [forum](http://groups.google.com/group/Pure-Unobtrusive-Rendering-Engine)

While it was primarly designed for the browser, it works well with Jaxer and Rhino.

I don't know node.js yet but if you can cache some JS and functions in memory, the speed should be even more impressive.

Comment: Node.js does not understand DOM... PURE use the DOM, but since it makes strings of it. This is interesting to investigate. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

There is a port of the Django templating engine to JavaScript. However, its not been updated for a long time but it may still have enough features.

http://code.google.com/p/jtl-javascript-template/

Answer (score 2):

Try [Yajet](http://www.yajet.net/) too. ;-)  It's a new one that I just released yesterday, but I'm using it for a while now and it's stable and fast (templates are compiled to a native JS function).

It has IMO the best syntax possible for a template engine, and a rich feature set despite its small code size (8.5K minified).  It has directives that allow you to introduce conditionals, iterate arrays/hashes, define reusable template components etc.

Comment: Interesting, nice work mishoo. Does it have any advantage over EJS?

Answer (score 0):

I found [hogan.js](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/) from Twitter and recommended by Tim O'Reilly on his site. I have no best practice with it, but I trust on Twitter and O'Reilly. You should try...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good evaluation of several engines
http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best and most simple template engine for Node.js is (IMHO) Plates (https://github.com/flatiron/plates). You might also want to check out the Flatiron MVC framework for Node.js (http://flatiron.org).

Answer (score -1):

You can use dojox.dtl of DojoToolkit.org. Note that dojo 1.7 can well run on NodeJS and perform as a server side library. If you're interested, I can give you a simple example.