# Templating engine for node.js

Tags: templates, node.js

I am looking for a templating engine with these specific requirements in mind:

Must have:

- logic support (if/else/etc)
- inclusions of files / inheritance (i.e. child/master templates)
- not HAML

Desirable:

- rich tags/filters (a-la Django)
- custom tags/filters

Comment: Why not do templating on the client side and simply return json to the client? Saves quite some bandwidth and if you load the JS templates via an ajax call instead of hacks like putting them in `<script type="text/html">` tags you don't even need invalid HTML for it.

Comment: You can look at that question, you will probably find your answer in it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787716/is-there-a-template-engine-for-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like *simonw*'s **[djangode](http://github.com/simonw/djangode/blob/master/TEMPLATES.md)** is what I need:

Here's how you load it:

```
loader.load_and_render('template.html', context, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        dj.default_show_500(req, res, error);
    } else {
        dj.respond(res, result, 'text/plain');
    }
});
```

And template syntax seems to be complete port of [Django 1.1 templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/templates/)

Answer (score 2):

[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) is looking like it will become the 'standard' templating language/engine for Node. It is sort of like HAML, except it's totally not HAML. It's way better.

It doesn't have master/child templates, but I've mentioned it to TJ (the author) and I will probably push for it. For now you just need to work bottom-up when rendering templates (ie. applying child templates to parent templates through variables), which I don't see as much of a problem in most cases.

**EDIT:** Jade does support inheritance now: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by 'standard'? Widest adoption? Eternal blessing by Ryan Dahl himself?

Comment: looks awful, I can't believe how many half-finished template engines there are out there for NodeJS that don't even come close to what you get when using Django or Rails