# jQuery templates on the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, serverside-javascript, envjs

Has anyone tried to use [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) (or any other JavaScript based templating) on the server side with something like [env.js](http://www.envjs.com/)?

I'm considering attempting it to see what benefits could be gained by being able to render identical templates on either the client or server side of a web application, but I was hoping someone might already have some experience, or know of an existing project doing this. I'd be particularly interested to know about any performance issues I might encounter compared to some more traditional templating engine.

To recap : Has anyone ever used jquery templates on the server site? If so, were there any performance issues, or other problems I might run into?

Comment: What exactly is your question? (see also [Is there a template engine for Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787716/is-there-a-template-engine-for-node-js))

Comment: Server side is more reliable because Client side you dont know about the users spec, and could dramatically decrease performance on user-end

Comment: You might want to look at @getify's blog (http://blog.getify.com/) - he rants about parity of templating and validation mechanisms between client and server *all the time*

Comment: Ball - To recap : Has anyone ever used jquery templates on the server site? If so, were there any performance issues, or other problems I might run into?

Comment: Just found this answer that suggests 2 jQuery template renderers in PHP and .Net respectively ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485419/server-side-templates-client-side-templates-automatic-conversion

Answer (score 4):

`env.js` is unnecessary.

`<plug shameless="true">`

I am in the process of specing and re-implementing JQuery templates to allow them to be used independently of the DOM.  See https://github.com/mikesamuel/jquery-jquery-tmpl-proposal for code, and demos.  The spec is available at http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template and it says:

> Text-centric rather than DOM dependent. Status: Done. See section 12 implementations. foo${bar} translates to something very similar to function (data, options) { return "foo" + bar; } modulo some dethunking of bar
>
> ...
>
> This will allow to use this template engine in server side javascript environment, such as node.js, or java/rhino

I would love feedback and can help you get started.

`</plug>`

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine working on a distributed Genetic Programing project used a js sevrer side template system to manage all the web workers spawned across all users browsers. His code is here: [github](https://github.com/ColinRoache/dPGP.js). I don't know how helpful it will be, but I know it was quite simple to implement and did some amazing things. From how easy he found it I would recommend a js template system it.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly trivial to write server side code to process the jQuery templates.

Here is [some *very* basic vb.net code](https://gist.github.com/994172) I have created that will return the result of a jquery template string to an array of any objects. Currently it only does the replacement of data values

```
Public Shared Function RenderTemplate(template As String, list As Array) As String
    Dim myRegexOptions As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions)
    Dim splits = myRegex.Split(template)
    Dim matches = myRegex.Matches(template)

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim swap As Boolean = False
    Dim str As New StringBuilder
    For Each item In list
        swap = False
        For i = 0 To splits.Length - 1
            If swap Then
                str.Append(CallByName(item, splits(i), CallType.Get, Nothing))
            Else
                str.Append(splits(i))
            End If
            swap = Not swap
        Next
    Next
    Return str.ToString
End Function
```

So if I sent in the following...

```
Dim strTargetString As String = "<p><a href='${Link}'>${Name}</a></p>"
Dim data As New Generic.List(Of TestClass)
data.Add(New TestClass With {.Link = "http://stackoverflow.com", .Name = "First Object"})
data.Add(New TestClass With {.Link = "http://stackexchange.com", .Name = "Second Object"})
Return Render(strTargetString, data.ToArray)
```

It would output it as a string

```
<p><a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>First Object</a></p>
<p><a href='http://stackexchange.com'>Second Object</a></p>
```

This will work alot faster than spawning up a fake browser object on the server, and running the whole jQuery library just to replace a few tags.

Comment: It's easy to render the simplest case templates, but what happens when the templates include function calls to JavaScript functions (which is not uncommon in real-world scenarios)?  That's tough without actually using JavaScript on the server-side.