# jQuery template and Backbone.js

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I am trying to create an app which uses a combination of jQuery templates and Backbone.js

I have very little experience in both of them (though I know jQuery)

Could you please provide some good examples where jQuery templates and Backbone.js are used effectively.
Also I am loooking at using JSON for the model/data and trying to persist the data (I use Java at the backend)..So looking for ideas on how that can be integrated?

Thank you.

Comment: Searching for "jQuery templates and backbone.js" seems like a prettty good starting point. First result: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/20/rendering-backbone-views-with-jquery-templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery template plugin has been removed and is not further developed (see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl). Better use something else or even the built-in to underscore _.template. There are plenty of examples around for instance [How to use underscore.js as a template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

Comment: Hmm...Any specific reasons why it has been discontinued...Also how useful is the underscore as template...Is it similar to what jaquery template provides? Any example would be really great...

Comment: The underscore one is useful enough that it's the only temp,acting language we use at work for JavaScript