# loops in underscore js template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Ok guys so I have this array of key pair values which I'm using as my model:

```
var acs = [{'label':'input box'},{'label':'text area'}];
```

the rest of the code goes as follows

```
var Action = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var action = new Action(acs);
var ActionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"li",
    template: _.template($('#actions-template').html()),
    events:{
        "click":"makeInput"
    },
    render:function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        $(".hero-unit>ul").append(this.el);
        return this;
    },
    makeInput:function(){
        alert("im in");
    }
});
var actionView = new ActionView({model:action});
actionView.render();
```

The question is with regards to the view. How can I loop through the model I'm passing if this is the view I want to have

```
<script type="text/template" id="actions-template">
<% _.each(action, function(acs) { %> 
    <a class="btn"><%= label %></a>
<% }); %>
</script>
```

There is something wrong with my view and the loop I believe. Any clues?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine has quite a few solutions too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'd probably want to do two things:

1. Adjust the data you supply to the template:

   ```
   $(this.el).html(this.template({
       action: this.model.toJSON()
   }));
   ```
2. Adjust the inner part of the template to use `acs.label` instead of `label`:

   ```
   <a class="btn"><%= acs.label %></a>
   ```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xczBy/

On second thought, I think you should be working with a collection rather than a single model. You'd want to add this:

```
var ActionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Action
});
```

And then adjust `render` to use `this.collection`:

```
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        actions: this.collection.toJSON()
    }));
```

And then start things up like this:

```
var actions = new ActionCollection(acs);
var actionView = new ActionView({collection: actions});
```

And finally, refer to `actions` in the template:

```
<% _.each(actions, function(acs) { %>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6VeXk/

This would better match Backbone's key/value based models.

Comment: one small question though, why is it action: this.model.toJSON() ?

Comment: @climboid: Your model was an array (which is odd in Backbone) and you need to give it a name of some sort or the template won't be able to refer to it. Models are normally sets of key/value pairs (more or less) so the values get names by default. Switching to a collection (as in my updated answer) would make more sense.