# How to have render big chunk of html inside a javascript forloop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html component that makes a variable amount of rows in a table.  Inside this component there are several css classes e.g

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:0">
```

How do I embed this big chunk of html in a javascript forloop? The only way I know how is to use document.write("") but the quotation marks in the classes will mess that up.

UPDATE:
Any ideas why the  tags and everything inside them is ignored when using innerHTML??

Comment: how does the *rest of the code* look like?

Comment: use single quotes.. document.write('');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a div with an id of `someDiv` (or whatever you want) for this to work.

```
document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = '<div class="row" style="margin-left:0">';
```

I used single quotes to wrap the string in order to avoid conflict with the double quotes in the HTML.

Comment: Any ideas why the <tr> tags and everything inside them is ignored when using innerHTML??

Comment: @James: They shouldn't be. But, I think this probably belongs in a separate question.

Comment: FYI problem#2 was occuring because I was inserting a div into a table, div must be a child of <th>

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape your quotes in your javascript.

```
alert('Oh, heya, I didn\'t see you, so "Hello"');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript isn't great for expressing HTML as, amongst other things, it lacks [Heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) syntax which results in you having to escape any string literals (as suggested by @DavidYell).

It might be worth considering the use of a [templating engine](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2012/using-external-templates-with-mustache-js-and-jquery/) such as [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) or [Underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

Comment: What!? Javascript isn't great for expressing HTML? Dude, Mustache and Underscore were *written* in Javascript.

Comment: ... and were designed because expressing HTML in Strings is a whole world of pain.  It's not like JavaScript even offers [E4X syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X) by default for working with XML.

Comment: All I can say is Javascript was designed explicitly for the purpose of working with (and that includes expressing) HTML. Underscore doesn't make that any easier.

Comment: Hi Elliot, I'm not trying to be difficult here, but expressing any form of XML in JavaScript is painful as you end up having to join a bunch of String literals together.  Templating engines provide a clean seperation between the template (HTML) and the data (JavaScript Objects) - if you haven't looked into one yet then may I suggest you have a look at this blog post: http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2012/using-external-templates-with-mustache-js-and-jquery/

Comment: Nice post. However, it's not *particularly* relevant in this case, as the OP has a very simple issue and installing a templating engine would be a bit like using a backhoe to till a garden. However, templating engines are quite nice when you're working on a really big project in which you're doing lots and lots of this sort of thing.