# Template engine supporting formatters

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine

Are there a javascript template engine which supports formatters?

That is, I can tell the template engine that it should be using a custom formatter (with a clean syntax).

Something like (borrowing jsrender syntax):

```
<td>{{:DateOfBirth, 'PrettyDate'}}</td>
```

Where `'PrettyDate'` is mapped to a function which formats the date in a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache supports lambda's, you can get the same effect.

http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: Lambdas are attached to the model, right? Not very extendable.

Answer (score 0):

[`jinjs`](https://github.com/Ravelsoft/node-jinjs), the JavaScript version of [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) supports filters which do pretty much what you want. In your case the syntax would be `{{ DAteOfBirth | PrettyDate }}`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**Underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/), it supports formatters, see: [How to use underscore.js as a template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

Answer (score 0):

[Distal](http://code.google.com/p/distal) templates supports formatters, see http://code.google.com/p/distal/wiki/Syntax#Formatting_data_into_numerical_form

It looks like:

```
<input data-qattr="value total_cost ,.">
```

where the ",." implies numbers with thousands separator (1,000,000.00)