# Unknown tags in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

In an example of backbone.js I find code in the HTML surrounded by `<%=` `%>`. I would like to know what syntax / language this is.

```
  <% if (managerName) { %>
    <li>
        <a href="#employees/<%= managerId %>">
            <div class="story">
                <b>View Manager</b><br/>
                <span class="metadata"><%= managerName %></span>
            </div>
            <img src="css/images/manager.png" class="action-icon"/>
        </a>
    </li>
  <% } %>
```

Sorry if this is basic question but googling it turns out to be harder than expected.

Comment: There are a number of languages that use the `<%` sequence.

Comment: Smells like ASP.NET, but looks like we're going to get an answer for **every** language that remotely looks like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is related to [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), it would be an [underscore.js template](http://underscorejs.org/#template). Have [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine) or [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2411-Using-Underscore-js-Templates-To-Render-HTML-Partials.htm) for some examples and more information on how to use it. One way to find out if it is used by a JavaScript templating engine would be to find out if it lives inside a `<script>` tag. It is quite likely that you copied that code snippet out of a script block that looked similar to this `<script type="text/template"></script>`, if it was an underscore.js template. I personally don't know any other JavaScript templating engines which use the exact same syntax as underscore.js, there could be another one out there.

Comment: Thank you. It is not included in <script type="text"/template>. The template is in a seperate HTML file which is then loaded through _.template method. I am looking more deeply into the underscore library.

Answer (score 2):

It is templating of Backbone.js not a language. This is executed through render method against a Model. Which know how to generate its html. You can not append this directly to DOM.

Something similar to [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/#demo)

Answer (score 0):

ASP has that syntax, not sure if anothers use it too.

Comment: A bunch do.  `<%` is one of the more common "hey, run this server-side" tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is similar to **JSP(Java Server Pages)**