# How do I create a macro or snippet for a repetitive HTML tag?

Tags: html

I'm writing some HTML code and I'm having trouble on trying to "summarize" if that's the right words multiple lines of code. Basically I have a select tag that I want to put many times in the HTML code but I don't want to re-writ eover and over again. What is the name for this action? Is it a macro? A snippet? An HTML function?

Basically:

```
<select>
<option value="default">-Select an Attribute-</option>
<option value="animal">animal</option>
<option value="person">person/human</option>
<option value="cat">cat</option>
<option value="dog">dog</option>
<option value="open">open space</option>
<option value="closed">closed space </option>
<option value="natural">natural</option>
<option value="artificial">artificial</option>
<option value="explicit">explicit</option>
<option value="sexual">sexual</option>
<option value="innocent">innocent</option>
<option value="fearful">fearful</option>
<option value="religious">religious</option>
</select>
```

Can I define a shortcut or a macro everytime I want to use that select tag code snippet? What's this process called in the HTML lingo, so I can have it in mind for future references?

Can't I do something like:

```
<select id="snippet">
</select>
```

that saves me the lines of code after doing a first definition?

Comment: You can't do that in plain HTML, but you could generate your HTML

Comment: How would I do that? *See question Edit*

Comment: You could generate your HTML by coding some script (or program) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not possible in plain HTML. You'd either need Javascript to do it client side, or a server-side script that did this for you using PHP, Python, Perl, etc...

**As an example of how to do this *client-side* using Javascript check out this code:** (See it in action at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2gV/)

```
options = {
    'default':'Select an Attribute',
    'animal':'animal',
    'person':'person/human'
};
$.each(options, function(key, value) {
    $('#mySelect')
    .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",key)
            .text(value)); 
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<form>
    Select: <select id="mySelect">
    </select>
</form>
```

**Alternatively with this *server-side* PHP code you get the same result** (You can see it in action here: http://codepad.org/O5zZ65tZ)

```
<form>
    Select: <select id="mySelect">
        <?php
            $options = array(
                   'default'=>'Select an Attribute',
                   'animal'=>'animal',
                   'person'=>'person/human'
            );
            foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>\n";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

But in both cases you aren't saving your self many keystrokes over just making the HTML yourself. You'd be best to ask a new question explaining your actual scenario and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, but what is the name of this process so I can google it? Is it called "creating a HTML macro", or something else?

Comment: It would be "how to generate HTML using X", where X is the language you want to/can use.

Comment: I like this answer, thanks. However I want to use the same select button multiple times (and with different id's), and there seems to be an error, because I need 3 inputs. I was thinking about doing something like 
<form>
    Attribute 1: <select id="mySelect" name="Attribute1"></select>
</form>

<form>
    Attribute 2: <select id="mySelect" name="Attribute2"></select>
</form>

<form>
    Attribute 3: <select id="mySelect" name="Attribute3"></select>
</form>
but it doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: I'd recommend that you put more clarifying information in your question. But you are a) going to need to learn some scripting be it client- or server-side, and b) going to have to input your options somewhere; the computer won't just figure out what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As Lego says, you can't do this in pure HTML. If you use JavaScript there are a few template libraries that could help. A couple I would suggest are:

- http://mustache.github.io/ - which is all about templates
- http://underscorejs.org/ - which has a simple to use template function

This post may help [How to use underscore.js as a template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

Comment: Ok, so basically I'd insert JS code inside my HTML code correct?

Comment: Correct, the answer on using underscore has some examples on how to do that. But basically you will insert <script> tags in your HTML and the browser will automatically run them.