# Syntax of JavaScript contains <%..%>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a project on top of some existing code written by another developer. It's a JavaScript project to build a chrome extension. One of the HTML files has some code written in the following format:

```
<% $.each(this, function(index, value) { %>

<% var valPart = value.from_mail.split('<'); %>
<% var name = valPart[0]; %>
<% var ma_name= name; %>
```

And some of the HTML tags on the page contain elements like

```
<a class='view_name' title='<%= value.fileName %>' href='<%= getViewUrl(value.viewUrl) %>'><%= value.fileName %></a>
```

`getViewUrl` is a function defined in the code. My main query is with the code between the <%...%>

Now, I have a fair idea that Embedded Ruby HTML files use `<% ... %>` for creating code elements inside the HTML file. I know for fact that Ruby isn't being used in this project or even ERB files for that matter. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: I guess that's asp syntax

Comment: It could be any templating language. Check the js files that load/display that markup to see how it is processed.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I don't think this is ASP because of the $.each on the first line, which is jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ I don't have any better suggestions though - it all looks like valid JavaScript but enclosed in ASP markup tags.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain certainly that's the jQuery part, I just commented for the `<%` syntax :)

Comment: @MikeChamberlain the code looks like JQuery, but the opening and closing tags(`<% %>`) look like ASP code. I would expect JQuery to open en close with: `<script type="text/javascript">
</script>`

Comment: It looks like underscore.js templating.

Comment: it may be a EJS template

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an underscore template: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: Looks like it. @Newtt, Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine) as well, it shows some templating similar to what you have.

Comment: Makes sense. However, doesn't underscore require to be installed in the project? I couldn't find any place where Underscore.js was installed or called into my project.

Answer (score 0):

I've inherited code with that same syntax in the html pages too. I'm working on an application which uses html, javascript and java. The code that I have uses <%=....%> syntax to reference java code and is called a scriplet. Perhaps that's your case as well? Below is from the oracle documentation for scriplets.

> JSP Scriptlets
>
> A JSP scriptlet is used to contain any code fragment that is valid for
>   the scripting language used in a page. The syntax for a scriptlet is
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> <%
>     scripting-language-statements
> %>
> ```
>
> When the scripting language is set to java, a scriptlet is transformed
>   into a Java programming language statement fragment and is inserted
>   into the service method of the JSP page’s servlet. A programming
>   language variable created within a scriptlet is accessible from
>   anywhere within the JSP page.
>
> In the web service version of the hello1 application, greeting.jsp
>   contains a scriptlet to retrieve the request parameter named username
>   and test whether it is empty. If the if statement evaluates to true,
>   the response page is included. Because the if statement opens a block,
>   the HTML markup would be followed by a scriptlet that closes the
>   block.
>
> ```
> <%
>    String username = request.getParameter("username");
>    if ( username != null && username.length() > 0 ) {
> %>
>        <%@include file="response.jsp" %> 
> <%
>    }
> %>
> ```

Here's the link to the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html