# Why does javascript fail with syntax error when parameter contains bracket?

Tags: javascript, html, scriptlet

I am calling a javascript function in the onLoad of the body element in one of my webpages. Looks like this:

```
 <body onLoad="initPage(<%=object.getStringWithBrackets()%>); otherfunction();">
```

`getStringWithBrackets()` is a java function and will return a string like this: "['Name']"

When this happens a syntax error occurs: `SyntaxError: syntax error initPage([`

And there's a little arrow that points to after the bracket.

If I surround the scriplet with single quotes, the little arrow points inbetween the single quotes and bracket: initPage('[.

Are we not allowed to pass strings with brackets as parameters?

**Edit:**
Thanks for the help so far. This is the line of html that is failing (I copied from the source after running into the error. I just changed names for the other function, everything else is untouched), I've put the single quotes back in around the scriplet to show the failure:

```
<body onLoad="initPage('["Print"]'); otherfunction('param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4', 'param5');">
```

Also wanted to mention that the java method `getStringWithBrackets()` is using Gson to return a json string version of java List(). That's how I get ["Print"].

Comment: Can you clarify **exactly** what that method returns? Don't use quotation marks when showing the value, show the actual characters that are in the return value and nothing else.

Comment: View the page source in browser and copy and paste the offending line here

Comment: I've added the line from the source in the browser. I think I may see the issue, the double quotes around Print may need to be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is that you're returning literally `"['Name']"` and you interpolate into an onLoad value that is itself wrapped in single quotes.  I can't trace exactly why you'd end up with precisely what you're saying you're getting, but I'm guessing you didn't supply us your *exact* javascript code and that the onLoad is wrapped in the same quotation as the `Name` ( here you show single quotes where the string is being terminated ). So you end up writing out html that looks like this:

The onload becomes "initPage([" ( from your error I'm seeing the onLoad setting is terminated after the `[` so it must have the same quotation as the onLoad string itself) and *that* of course, is not valid javascript.

You *can* of course pass strings with parameters as javascript.  You can also pass arrays as parameters.  But you cannot write both `'` and `"` into a javascript expression which is itself enquoted with either one, unless you escape it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you may be right. I just updated my question. Let me try to escape and see if that helps. Would you suggest a better way of going about this other than to escape the extra quotes? This will eventually become a list of different strings in a list.

Comment: Hi, I'm definitely right, looking at your well made edit above.  From the exerpt `onLoad="initPage('["Print"]');` you can see that the onLoad value ends at the `"` just before `Print` - causing both a syntax error and a truncated javascript.  My preferred method would be to set the variable in a piece of un-enquoted javascript ( assuming it's being written out on the server side, set it as `<script>initPageValue='["Print"]'</script>` and then use `onLoad="initPage(initPageValue)..."`- Inline JS should be minimized.  You might also consider whether you could use better format than `'["Print"]'`

Comment: Hah! That's what I exactly did. I ended up saving the value of the java method into a variable and then referencing that variable when calling the javascript function. Thanks again for the help Dan!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the quotes around the string value.  Your asp.net code will return a string, but you need to have quotes around it to be treated as a string in javascript:

```
<body onLoad="initPage('<%=object.getStringWithBrackets()%>'); otherfunction();">
```

Comment: I think that the function expects an Array, or what he's doing wouldn't make much sense (at least to me)

Comment: yeah, either way more info is needed to confirm since we all have different assumptions!  But I can certainly see your point.

Comment: @ps2goat I did have single quotes to begin with and it didn't seem to work. There's no use of asp.net. Just javascript, html and java.

Comment: ok.  Where is the `<%= %>` syntax coming from, then?  I'm familiar with that in asp.net webforms code.

Comment: You can check my answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298591/syntax-of-javascript-contains/22485788#22485788