# Underscore's template method with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

On the Underscore.js site, we're given the code example:

```
var list = "<% _.each(people, function(name) { %> <li><%= name %></li> <% }); %>";
_.template(list, {people: ['moe', 'curly', 'larry']});

=> "<li>moe</li><li>curly</li><li>larry</li>"
```

Lets assume that I want to pass 2 array of values instead of 1 (@ people). So that I could do something like:

```
{ %> <li><%= name %> , <%= address %></li> <% }
```

I tinkered around for a bit and wasn't sure how to use the method for this.

Comment: You mean an array of names and an array of adresses? Better pass an array of objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use underscore.js as a template engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'd have to make the array into an array of objects with "name" and "address" properties:

```
_.template(list, {people: [ 
    { name: 'moe', address: 'foo'}, 
    { name: 'curly', address: 'bar' } 
] });
```

Then the parameter would be the object "person" instead of just the string "name":

```
var list = "<% _.each(people, function(person) { %> <li>Name: <%= person.name %>, Address: <%= person.address %></li> <% }); %>";
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves it for me. I'll accept this when the timer dies out.