# Template Engines for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to find the solution of my question "What is template engine for Javascript ?", but i wasn't able to find an simple answer. Can anyone tell me the answer of this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396

Comment: Do you know what templates are?

Comment: Templates contain some html elements(code) which we can use while devloping web pages. @Bergi

Comment: Then a template engine is a piece of software that takes these templates and produces the web page. "for JavaScript" means that the engine is written in JS and/or has a JS API.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks bud

Answer (score 0):

"engine" is a stupid word for it. it's just a way to write HTML from javascript, with some "brains" so it could be written like HTML but you could mix it up with javascript logic and do loops and checks and whatever..inject dynamic javascript content..you get the point.

Plenty on this on this website - [How to use underscore.js as a template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4778881/104380)

Comment: SO is it like implementing some readymade code for what you want to do?

Comment: lets say you have a "to-do" list, where someone inputs an item to the list. so, you gonna write an  HTML template file, so javascript would know the markup of how an item of this list looks like, and them fill it up with data. so, you give "brains" to your HTML, it would now know what data should go where, instead of hard-coding HTML using javascript strings, and then inject it to the page.