# Retrieve column in Parse

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am working with Parse for Javascript, and I have managed to store items in columns in parse called Subject and Message, but my problem is that I would like to display all of them.

Below is the javascript code:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); 

var Message = Parse.Object.extend("Message"); 

var query = new Parse.Query(Message); 
query.equalTo("user", currentUser); 
query.find({ 
success: function(messages) { 

} 
});
```

My problem is in relating the javascript code to the html so that it displays all of the message with its subject in a table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)'s templating functionality. Here's an example of how to use it:

#### JS

```
// Using Underscore.js to create a function called 'template'
var template = _.template($('#messages-template').text());

// Passing in an object as an argument to the 'template' function
var compiled = template({ messages: <array of messages from Parse> });

// Appending into the body the HTML that was created from merging the object into the template
$(body).append(compiled);
```

#### HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="messages-template">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <% messages.forEach(function(message) { %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= message %></td>
        </tr>
      <% }); %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Be sure to check out the docs for a better understanding of how to use it to it's fullest capabilities - http://underscorejs.org/#template .