# underscore.js template function referenceError

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore.js template function on the following code based on http://underscorejs.org/#template and other tutorials

```
json = {"data": [{"img0": "image.jpg"}]}
var compiled = _.template("image: <%= img0 %>");
compiled(json.data[0]);
document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML = compiled();
```

but i got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: img0 is not defined
```

Can you explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: i already check similar question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass arguments to template function when you call it,

```js
var json = {"data": [{"img0": "image.jpg"}]};
var compiled = _.template("image: <%= img0 %>");

document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML = compiled(json.data[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="albums"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand now what the problem was :)