# Backbone tpl files syntax full documentation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Being new in Backbone, i try to find a documentation for the tpl files, (or underscore) to answer simple questions like:

```
 <% for(var i in array) { %>
    <% var j = i+1 %>
    // here i want a sum of 2 integer but it is added as 2 strings
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If im reading the question properly your looking for links on underscores template syntax.

[How to use underscore.js as a template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778881/how-to-use-underscore-js-as-a-template-engine)

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2411-using-underscore-js-templates-to-render-html-partials.htm