# Underscore JS: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I know that there are lots of similar questions on SO but none of the ones I checked could fix my issue.

I used this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPv9H/626/) referenced in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389847/2025481) about Underscore templating.

So here is my template:

```
        <script type="text/html" id="forecastTemplate">
            <table class="forecast-table">
                <tbody>
                 <% _.each(items,function(item,key,list){ 

                    var day = moment.unix(item.dt).format("ddd");
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= day %></td>
                    <td><span><%= item.temp.min %></span><span class="wi wi-celsius"></span></td>
                    <td><span><%= item.temp.max %></span><span class="wi wi-celsius"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="wi wi-rain"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <% }); %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </script>
```

It seems clear that the issue is with the _.each line but I can't see where the problem is...

Do you guys see what I can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, you have `<% }); %}` where it should be `<% }); %>`
;)

Comment: Damn, that was a stupid one! Very good catch! I cannot accept the answer yet but I will as soon as I can!

Comment: Sometimes you just don't see it. It means coffee or break :D