# NodeJS: Serving dynamic files

Tags: node.js, express

I've been used to PHP, where code is put in a file, and executed each time on load.

With NodeJS, I need to use HTML files, but need calculation done within the files. A solution would be putting the whole file's HTML content into the file that is running the HTTP server, but I'd like to have them in files instead.

I am using NodeJS, and Express. How is this done?

Comment: Do your work within your Node application itself.  That's the whole point.

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1787716/362536  Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: I do, but if I'm serving a lot of HTML files, I'd prefer to have them in a directory and serve them from there.

Comment: You can still do that!  That is absolutely encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using express and want to render HTML files you should use `ejs` as your template engine. Here is how you do it from scratch:

start a new project with `express -e`

tell `express` to use `ejs` for rendering HTML files:

```
app.configure(function(){
  // ... 
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  // app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  // ...
});
```

create a route:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("your.html", {
    title: "This is plain HTML rendered with ejs"
  })
})
```

and finally your `your.html` file in the `views` folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use templates, here is an example:

https://github.com/chovy/express-template-demo