# How to load an external js file from another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following express code for get method:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
app.listen(3000);
```

I want this code snippet to do:

1. load a js file from a different server
2. embed this js file inside the index.html file that was brought by the get request.

Comment: Are they both on the same domain? (Can this even be done server side...?)

Comment: Do you want to add a `script` tag to `index.html` ? If so, should it contain the URL to the script on the other server ? Or the content of the script itself ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox -  no. The js file will have to be brought from different domain.

Comment: 1. https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD1t6MlOzRAhXGOhQKHbXiAvAQPAgD#safe=off&hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+node.js+make+http+request 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787716/is-there-a-template-engine-for-node-js

Comment: @A.Perrot - I want to bring the content. The index.html file cannot be changed. I want an external operation that inserts the content of js file into the index.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to fetch the distant js file with an http request : see [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Then, you want to use a template engine to insert the content of the file into `index.html` (which has to be ready to be templated), see [express doc about template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).